# React: Why isn't the YouTube player state rendering?

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api, components, video-player

I'm currently working on a personal project to embed a YouTube video and render the current state of the video player on the page using a YouTube API call to getPlayerState(). Here's the code I have right now, and my logic was that I could update playerState depending on what the getPlayerState function returns.

Here's the API function: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status.

However, the playerState that comes up on the page never updates. It just always stays at Unstarted, which is what I initialized to, even after the video starts playing.

Would someone mind explaining what error I might be encountering, and a possible fix? I've looked at this for a long time and can't quite figure out why this is. Thank you so much!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from "react-player"

class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            playerState: "Unstarted",
            youtubeIsClicked: false,
        };
    }

    handleVideoPlayerState = (e) => {
        this.currentVideoPlayerState(e);
    }

    currentVideoPlayerState = async (e) => {
        let [currentPlayerState] = await Promise.all([
            e.target.getPlayerState()
        ]);

        switch (currentPlayerState) {
            case -1:
                console.log('onPlayerStateChange', currentPlayerState);
                this.setState({ playerState: "Unstarted" })
                break;
            case 0:
                console.log('onPlayerStateChange', currentPlayerState);
                this.setState({ playerState: "Ended" })
                break;
            case 1:
                console.log('onPlayerStateChange', currentPlayerState);
                this.setState({ playerState: "Playing" })
                break;
            case 2:
                console.log('onPlayerStateChange', currentPlayerState);
                this.setState({ playerState: "Paused" })
                break;
            case 3:
                console.log('onPlayerStateChange', currentPlayerState);
                this.setState({ playerState: "Buffering" })
                break;
            case 5:
                console.log('onPlayerStateChange', currentPlayerState);
                this.setState({ playerState: "Video cued" })
                break;
        }
    }

    handleYouTubeClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            youtubeIsClicked: true,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ width: "80%", margin: "0 auto" }}>
                <h1>Video Player</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleYouTubeClick}>Youtube</button>
                {this.state.youtubeIsClicked && (
                    <div>
                        <ReactPlayer
                            url="https://youtu.be/2XsP4I9ds4c"
                            playerState={this.state.playerState}
                            onPlayerStateChange={this.handleVideoPlayerState}
                        />
                        <p>Playback State: {this.state.playerState}</p>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default YouTubePlayer
```

Comment: For reference, I'm using CookPete's React Player package.

Answer (score 0):

handleVideoPlayerState() is never called. You need to create a button and then have it handle this situation

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? I don't think I want to create a new button. I would like to get the information directly from the YouTube video embedded using a call to the YouTube API. This is the information that isn't getting rendered.

Answer (score 0):

`playerState` and `onPlayerStateChange` are not accepted props of `ReactPlayer`. They are part of YouTube's IFrame Player API, which you linked above. ReactPlayer may work with YouTube's API under the hood, but it adds another layer of abstraction, and you can't directly interact with the YouTube API through ReactPlayer.

To access the YouTube player instance directly, you can use [refs](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/blob/9d4794137489c141cbffbdf2ddcdf5c2be803b2d/src/demo/App.js#L147) and ReactPlayer's [`getInternalPlayer()`](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player#instance-methods) function: `var ytplayer = reactplayer.getInternalPlayer()`. You can then call [`ytplayer.addEventListener()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Adding_event_listener) to add your handler to the `onPlayerStateChange` event.

As you can see, this would be additional overhead. It might be easier to just skip `ReactPlayer` entirely and work directly with the YouTube API.

Comment: I see, I had originally chosen ReactPlayer since I wanted to do both a YouTube and a DailyMotion video. Thank you for the suggestion! I will try this and let you know.